# Javascript to validate form NullpointerException

Tags: forms, jsp, validation

Following this very bad book that's giving me lots of headache but I don't know why I keep reading it.

It's obvious that user.getEmailAddress() is going to be null so it's giving me this error, but removing it doesn't work(i.e. submit not submitting, and any textbox after the first textbox doesn't validate) so I just want to type exactly what the book shows to see how it goes but of course it doesn't compile.
Could anyone give some suggestion? thanks.

```
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Email address:</td>
                <td> <input type="email" name="email"
                            value="<%= user.getEmailAddress() %>"
                            placeholder="Enter a valid email address"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><br><input type="button" value="Submit"
                               onClick="validate(this.form)"></td>
            </tr>
```

http://s1.uploads.im/5v3gY.png

Above is a link to the code page in the book.

Comment: As a side note, the book is showing you a lot of bad practices, such as the use of tables for design rather than to display structured data, and the use of inline JavaScript event handlers.

Comment: If you get a NullPointerException then its not because `user.getEmailAddress()` is null but because `user` is null. NullPointerException is from using the dot operator on an object that is null.

Comment: Ya whatever, do you know how to fix it? I added a if(user == null) user = new User(); it will run but it doesn't validate and the Submit button never does anything even if I type all the infos in. Is something wrong with the code the book provided?

Comment: show your java code where this exception raises and the exception stack trace too.

Comment: well the exception is from user.getStuff() because user wasn't initialized. So the code must be the javascript code or the onClick="validate(this.form)". Can you tell if something is wrong with that code? It does not validate data, and the button does nothing.